# How do I add incrementing numbers starting from an user's input to the footer of a Word document using VBA code?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro using VBA in Microsoft Word that will do the following:

1. Take an input of a starting number and an ending number.
2. Insert the number of pages that is the difference between the starting number and ending number minus one (to account for the original page) into the document.
3. Add the respective numbers to the footer of each page.

So, if the inputted starting number is 5 and the ending number is 10, a total of 5 new pages should be inserted into the document. Then, the first page's footer should say "Page 5", the second "Page 6", etc. etc. all the way to "Page 10".

This code works well to insert the pages, but beyond that, I can't get the numbers to properly insert.

```
Sub InsertPages()
    Dim startPage As Integer
    Dim endPage As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Prompt the user to input the starting and ending page numbers
    startPage = InputBox("Enter the starting page number:", "Starting Page")
    endPage = InputBox("Enter the ending page number:", "Ending Page")
    
    ' Validate input
    If startPage >= endPage Or startPage < 1 Or endPage < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid page numbers. Please enter valid page numbers.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through and insert pages
    For i = startPage To endPage - 1
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: section break + static page number as text

To get each page has its own footer, two conditions must be met:

- Unlink header and footer from the previous section
- Each page in a different section

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [WdBreakType enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbreaktype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.headerfooter.linktoprevious?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm159711238)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub InsertPageFooter()
    Dim oSec As Section, oRng As Range, i As Long
    Dim startPage As Long
    Dim endPage As Long
    ' Prompt the user to input the starting and ending page numbers
    startPage = InputBox("Enter the starting page number:", "Starting Page")
    endPage = InputBox("Enter the ending page number:", "Ending Page")
    ' Use initial values for testing
    ' startPage = 5: endPage = 10 ' for testing
    ' Validate input
    If startPage >= endPage Or startPage < 1 Or endPage < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid page numbers. Please enter valid page numbers.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Insert Section Break
    For i = startPage To endPage - 1
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Next
    i = 0
    ' Update footer
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
        Set oRng = oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        oRng.Text = "Page " & startPage + i
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Option 2: page break + PAGE field

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub InsertPageFooter2()
    Dim oSec As Section, oRng As Range, i As Long
    Dim startPage As Long
    Dim endPage As Long
    ' Prompt the user to input the starting and ending page numbers
    startPage = InputBox("Enter the starting page number:", "Starting Page")
    endPage = InputBox("Enter the ending page number:", "Ending Page")
    ' Use initial values for testing
'    startPage = 5: endPage = 10 ' for testing
    ' Validate input
    If startPage >= endPage Or startPage < 1 Or endPage < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid page numbers. Please enter valid page numbers.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Insert Page Break
    For i = startPage To endPage - 1
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Next
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        Set oRng = .Range
        oRng.Fields.Add Range:=oRng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
        oRng.InsertBefore "Page "
        oRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        With .PageNumbers
            .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
            .StartingNumber = startPage
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @TimothyRylatt  I've updated the code. I'm unsure why the `StartingNumber` setting wasn't functioning as expected without a convoluted selection process yesterday. It's possible that the document is corrupted. I've successfully tested it with a newly created file. Regardless, I appreciate your comment confirming it.

Comment: Note that a separate section for every page is going to give you a very complex document structure that will be difficult to edit. My preference would be to use field coding instead but my vba skills and interest are not up to it. See also: Word does not know what a page is by MVP Daiya Mitchell. https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html I cringe every time someone discusses adding or deleting pages.

Answer (score -1):

Sub AddIncrementingNumbersToFooter()

' Get user input for starting number
Dim StartNumber As Integer
StartNumber = InputBox("Enter the starting number:", "Number Input")

' Check if a valid number was entered
If IsNumeric(StartNumber) Then
' Go to the first page footer
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Select

```
' Insert the starting number and a bookmark
With Selection
    .TypeText Chr(13) ' Move to a new line
    .InsertAfter "SerialNumber " & StartNumber
    .Bookmarks.Add Name:="SerialNumber"
End With

' Loop through all pages except the first
For i = 2 To ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Pages.Count
    ' Go to the footer of the current page
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Select
    ' Move to the bookmark
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="SerialNumber"
    ' Increment the number and update the text
    StartNumber = StartNumber + 1
    Selection.TypeText Chr(13) ' Move to a new line
    Selection.InsertAfter "SerialNumber " & StartNumber
Next i

' Set the focus back to the document
ActiveWindow.Activate
```

Else
MsgBox "Please enter a valid number."
End If

End Sub

Comment: Have you tested the code? [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)